# Issue Azure translation API is when I wants to translate text with some special characters like %,=,=>,# API respond with 500 Internal server error

Tags: azure, api, translation

Recently I migrated MS Azure Translation API to V3 as V2 getting decomissioned this APRIL. Issue is when I wants to translate text containing some special characters like %,#,=,=> API respond 500 internal server error. Its unable to detect that characters.Is this bug with V3 azure translation API.

```
        System.Object[] body = new System.Object[] { new { Text = @textToTranslate } };
        var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(host + detectPath + "&" + requestBody);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", key);
        client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        var detetctContent = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var responseMessage = client.PostAsync(client.BaseAddress, detetctContent).Result;  //here is the error comes have I missed something.
```

MS Azure translation API should recognized special characters as like V2 version.